# Proof for the Binomial expansion for $(1+x)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, education, binomial-theorem

At A level, is there a proof for the Binomial expansion for $(1+x)^n$ where $n$ is rational but not an integer, and $|x| < 1$, i.e., where $(1+x)^n = 1 + nx + (n(n-1)/2!)x^2 +\ldots$ or do we just have to accept it without any proof?

Comment: Of course you don't just accept it without any proof... but the proof might be a bit outside your grasp at A level.  Have you yet studied calculus?  Reimann sums?  Differential Equations?  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124293/generalized-binomial-theorem), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38950/prove-that-1-x-frac1b-is-a-formal-power-series?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45801/simple-proof-of-the-binomial-theorem-for-mathbbr) for starters

Comment: I haven't known the proof, but I saw two proofs on Wikipedia and I think it'd be better you checked them out before ask this question.

Comment: " or do we just have to accept it without any proof?" At A Level I would accept this particular theorem without proof. Just make sure to memorise the expansion correctly. You can go into detail of the proof later on (uni or self-study).

Comment: There is a proof on page 82 of my (very) old A-level textbook: Clement V. Durell, *Advanced Algebra*, Vol. I (1932). I don't have time to type it up today, but I'll try to get round to it soon. It can be read online [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.502134/page/n91/mode/2up), and it may be freely downloaded.

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley Thank you for this. I'll take a look at it immediately.

Comment: I don't have time to deal with this now, but I intend to request that the question be reopened, because the cited "duplicate" is not one. Even if the proof given in answer to the other question is valid - it is so unclear, I can't tell - it employs (i) the gamma function (or factorial notation for numbers other than non-negative integers), (ii) an identity theorem for power series, (iii) a uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations. Not only are none of these ideas necessary, but I doubt if they have ever been taught at A-level (although I'm open to correction on that point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at it as the same as your ol' expansion, just that binomial coefficients are replaced by their definitions because we define factorials of rationals differently. For example, $$\binom{n}{0}=1,\ \binom{n}{1}=n,\ \binom{n}{2}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!},\ \cdots$$This might help in remembering the formula, but as said already, a proof is beyond your scope.

You can satisfy your curiosity by actually learning around some of these concepts, that would take a lot of time and devotion though, presuming you are a high school student.

Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this proof is based on page 82 of an A-level text from 1932: [Advanced Algebra Vol.1 : Durell, Clement V](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.502134/page/n91/mode/2up).

Let $\alpha$ be any real number, and $x$ any real number such that
$|x| < 1.$ Consider the infinite series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}nx^n,
$$
where
$$
\binom{\alpha}n = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}.
$$
(The empty product expression for $n = 0$ evaluates to $1.$) Note
the identity:
\begin{equation}
\label{4259137:eq:1}\tag{1}
(n + 1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1} = (\alpha - n)\binom{\alpha}n,
\end{equation}
valid for all $n.$

For each $n \geqslant 1,$ let $f_n(x)$ be the sum of the first $n$
terms of that infinite series:
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{\alpha}rx^r.
$$
Differentiating:
$$
f_n'(x) = \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}r\binom{\alpha}rx^{r-1} =
\alpha + \sum_{r=1}^{n-2}(r+1)\binom{\alpha}{r+1}x^r,
$$
whence:
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{{}={}} (1 + x)f_n'(x) - \alpha f_n(x) \\
& = \sum_{r=1}^{n-2}\left[(r+1)\binom{\alpha}{r+1} +
(r-\alpha)\binom{\alpha}r\right]x^r +
(n-1-\alpha)\binom{\alpha}{n-1}x^{n-1} \\
& = -n\binom{\alpha}nx^{n-1},
\end{align*}
by \eqref{4259137:eq:1}. Therefore:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{f_n(x)}{(1 + x)^\alpha}\right] =
-\frac{n\binom{\alpha}nx^{n-1}}{(1 + x)^{\alpha+1}} \qquad (x > -1).
$$
Integrating (note that the integral expression makes sense even when
$x \leqslant 0$):
\begin{equation}
\label{4259137:eq:2}\tag{2}
\frac{f_n(x)}{(1 + x)^\alpha} - 1 =
-\binom{\alpha}n\int_0^x\frac{nt^{n-1}}{(1+t)^{\alpha+1}}\,dt.
\end{equation}
If we can show, for all $x$ such that $|x| < 1,$ that the expression
on the right hand side of \eqref{4259137:eq:2} tends to $0$ as $n$
tends to infinity, then it will follow that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_n(x)}{(1 + x)^\alpha} = 1.
$$
That is, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = (1 + x)^\alpha,$ and this means:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}nx^n = (1 + x)^\alpha
\qquad (|x| < 1).
$$

The denominator of the integrand in \eqref{4259137:eq:2} is always
positive (for all values of $t$ in the interval $[0, x]$ if $x$ is
positive, or the interval $[x, 0]$ if $x$ is negative). The sign of
the numerator is constant; it is positive for all $t$ if $x$ is
positive or if $n$ is odd, and it is negative for all $t$ if $x$ is
negative and if $n$ is even.  Therefore the absolute value of the
integral is increased, or at least it is not decreased, if we
replace the integrand by another integrand of greater absolute
value.  Since the denominator has its smallest value when $x$ is
negative and $t = x,$ we certainly have:
$$
\left\lvert\int_0^x\frac{nt^{n-1}}{(1+t)^{\alpha+1}}\,dt\right\rvert
\leqslant \int_0^{|x|}\frac{nt^{n-1}}{(1-|x|)^{\alpha+1}}\,dt
= \frac{|x|^n}{(1-|x|)^{\alpha+1}}.
$$
(The denominator of this expression can be omitted if $x > 0,$ but
it doesn't matter, because we are only interested in the behaviour
of the expression as $n$ tends to infinity.) Therefore, from
\eqref{4259137:eq:2}:
\begin{equation}
\label{4259137:eq:3}\tag{3}
(1-|x|)^{\alpha+1}
\left\lvert\frac{f_n(x)}{(1 + x)^\alpha} - 1\right\rvert \leqslant
\left\lvert\binom{\alpha}n\right\rvert|x|^n.
\end{equation}
But for all $n > \alpha,$ we have (ignoring the trivial case $x=0$):
$$
\frac{\left\lvert\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\right\rvert|x|^{n+1}}
{\left\lvert\binom{\alpha}n\right\rvert|x|^n} =
\frac{n - \alpha}{n + 1}|x| =
\left(1 - \frac{\alpha + 1}{n + 1}\right)|x|
\to |x| \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$
Therefore, for all sufficiently large values of $n,$ the ratio of
successive terms of the sequence on the right hand side of
\eqref{4259137:eq:3} - of course, this is just the $n^\text{th}$ term
of the original infinite series, with $|x|$ in place of $x$ - is
strictly less than $1.$ If we denote the sequence by $(u_n),$ then
there exists a number $a$ such that $|x| < a < 1$ and a positive
integer $N$ such that $u_n < u_Na^{n - N}$ for all $n > N.$ It
would not be difficult to give exact values for $a$ and $N$ in
terms of $\alpha$ and $|x|,$ but it doesn't matter.  The important
thing is that $a^{n - N} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty,$ therefore
$u_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$ This completes the proof.

---

(This part is optional!)

Although the argument above is quite short and direct, deriving the sum of
the infinite series almost from first principles, the part where it
uses integration is quite obscure. (I found it obscure in the
original version, and it is still obscure in my version.) It might
be better, therefore, to avoid the use of integration altogether.
The theorem on the existence of the integral of a general continuous
function on a bounded closed interval is not needed, because all the
integrands involved have known primitives, i.e., antiderivatives.
All we need is the theorem that a function whose derivative is
positive on an interval is increasing on that interval. (This is a
consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.)

Given $x$ such that $|x| < 1,$ define, for all $t > -1$:
\begin{align*}
F(t) & = \frac{f_n(t)}{(1 + t)^\alpha} - 1, \\
G(t) & = \frac{-\binom{\alpha}nt^n}{(1-|x|)^{\alpha+1}}.
\end{align*}
(As before: we could omit the denominator of $G(t)$ if $x > 0,$ but
it does no harm to leave it in.)
Then $F(0) = G(0) = 0,$ and, as shown above:
\begin{align*}
F'(t) & = \frac{-n\binom{\alpha}nt^{n-1}}{(1+t)^{\alpha+1}}, \\
G'(t) & = \frac{-n\binom{\alpha}nt^{n-1}}{(1-|x|)^{\alpha+1}}.
\end{align*}

Assume, for simplicity, that $\alpha$ is not a positive integer or
zero. (The finite case of the Binomial Theorem can be assumed to be
already known.) Then $\binom{\alpha}n \ne 0$ for all integers
$n \geqslant 0.$
If $x > 0,$ then for all $t \in (0, x]$ we have
$$
0 > \frac{F'(t)}{\binom{\alpha}n} > \frac{G'(t)}{\binom{\alpha}n}.
$$
If $x < 0$ and $n$ is odd, then the same inequalities hold for all
$t \in [x, 0).$ On the other hand, if $x < 0$ and $n$ is even, then
for all $t \in [x, 0)$ we have
$$
0 < \frac{F'(t)}{\binom{\alpha}n} < \frac{G'(t)}{\binom{\alpha}n}.
$$
In all cases, therefore, the derivatives of the functions
$F,$ $G,$ and $G - F$ have the same constant sign for all $t$
between $0$ and $x.$ Regardless of whether that sign is positive or
negative, the initial condition $F(0) = G(0) = 0$ implies that
$|F(x)| \leqslant |G(x)|,$ which is inequality \eqref{4259137:eq:3}
above; and the argument is completed as before.

If anything, though, I find this argument harder, not easier to
follow than the one involving an integral expression, even though
technically it is simpler.

Comment: I can't remember what we studied for A-levels in the late 1960s, but it must surely have included the use of the Ratio Test to prove convergence, and at least a statement, if not a proof, of the result that a convergent power series is differentiable on its interval of convergence. If these tools are available, one can work with the sum to infinity, $f(x),$ instead of the partial sums, $f_n(x).$ This eliminates the fiddly part of the above proof. (It isn't necessary to use Taylor series with the Cauchy form of the remainder, or any theorem on uniqueness of solutions to differential equations.)

Comment: I've almost finished writing an extension of my answer, giving a full proof along the lines suggested in that comment - I'm still trying to keep within the bounds of what might conceivably be taught at A-level, even if it never has been - but I'll try to get the question reopened first. I'd be interested to read other answers, perhaps expounding what is written on the topic in modern A-level textbooks. (I'm out of touch with education, and don't even know where to start looking. I did Google some recent syllabi, and the A-level syllabus does seem to have shrunk in some respects since my day.)